# create test case for web service , soap and rest

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, testing, soap

i am developing soa system. i develop some web services(web methods) and need to test all them.
i need to create test case, test result and i want to can save all these tests in a project or solution. i develop some soap web services, i need to send deferent parameters (correct and incorect) to testing application.
please help me, is there any tools or solution for test web services and create test case and save theme in a project? publicly the others developers use what tools ? what is the best way.
i need to save result of testing for future. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use soapUI for create test case and you can save all test in a project.
soapUI is very usefull tool for work with webservices. see [this](https://www.soapui.org/search.html#search/test/category/All) for more  information. soapUI have good documetation.

Answer (score 0):

[Swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) is Perl, curl based DSL for web services test automation. Test  reports generated are simple text files in [TAP](http://testanything.org) format which have many parsers and portable on many systems.

Disclosure - I am the author of swat.